# Subquery for left join in association scope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, orm, left-join

I use Rails 4.2.0 with ActiveRecord. I have `Case` model, which `has_many :notes`.

My main goal is to get latest note for each case in one query. Note fields should be sortable (`ORDER BY notes.created_at`, for example) I could achieve this by such SQL query:

```
SELECT cases.*, notes.* FROM cases
LEFT OUTER JOIN notes ON cases.id = notes.case_id AND notes.id = (
  SELECT id FROM notes 
  WHERE notes.case_id = cases.id 
  ORDER BY notes.created_at DESC 
  LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY notes.created_at DESC
```

My current `case.rb` code is following:

```
has_one :latest_note, -> do
  where('id' => Note.where('"case_id" = "cases"."id"').order(created_at: :desc).limit(1))
end, inverse_of: :case, class_name: 'Note'
```

It works fine, when `eager_load` is used: `Case.eager_load(:latest_note).order('notes.created_at DESC')`

```
SELECT "cases"."id" AS t0_r0, "cases"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "cases"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "notes"."id" AS t1_r0, "notes"."case_id" AS t1_r1, "notes"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "notes"."updated_at" AS t1_r3
FROM "cases" LEFT OUTER JOIN "notes" 
  ON "notes"."case_id" = "cases"."id" 
  AND "notes"."id" IN (
    SELECT  "notes"."id" FROM "notes" 
    WHERE ("case_id" = "cases"."id")  
    ORDER BY "notes"."created_at" DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)  ORDER BY notes.created_at DESC
```

But raises error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cases.id` without `eager_load`:
`Case.first.latest_note`

```
SELECT  "notes".* FROM "notes" 
WHERE "notes"."case_id" = ? AND "notes"."id" IN (
  SELECT  "notes"."id" FROM "notes" 
  WHERE ("case_id" = "cases"."id")  
  ORDER BY "notes"."created_at" DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) LIMIT 1
```

P.S. Is there solution without association scopes? Raw left joins via `joins` don't work with `eager_load`. Without `eager_load` it doesn't map values from Database to objects - dates stay as string, not `DateTime` objects.

Answer (score 3):

I've just found the workaround:

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) I've found, that scope can accept the owner object as argument:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :birthday_events, ->(user) { where starts_on: user.birthday }, class_name: 'Event'
end
```

So, my relation became:

```
has_one :latest_note, ->(kase) do
  subquery = Note.order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
  subquery = kase.is_a?(Case) ? subquery.where(case_id: kase.id) : subquery.where('"case_id" = "cases"."id"')
  where('id' => subquery)
end, inverse_of: :case, class_name: 'Note'
```

However, `Rails 4.2.0` outputs:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The association scope 'latest_note' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading happens before the individual instances are created. This means that there is no instance being passed to the association scope. This will most likely result in broken or incorrect behavior. Joining, Preloading and eager loading of these associations is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Also, this workaround doesn't work with `preload` (separate SQL query)

Comment: avoid the warning by using a join instead of an instance-dependent where clause: `has_many :birthday_events, ->{ joins("JOIN events on events.starts_on = users.birthday" }, class_name: 'Event'`